# Desperate total beginner asking: How to wire tiny LEDs of different types for mini-sculpture "flame" effect?

Tags: led

I'm a bacteriologist-turned-info analyst-turned-retirement age craftsperson trying to figure out how to add a simple small LED part to my projects.  I am doing very small wood sculptures (one is less than 2" tall) shaped a bit like layers of curled abstract leaf/petal shapes.  I got the notion of doing a sort of flame effect inside of tiny (half inch or so) glass "bubble beads" to go into them.

I've searched through the StackExchange "similar questions", and I've tried to figure out "arduino", I am currently making my way through "Arduino for Dummies", trying to learn what I need if I used TinyCircuits and how to connect the parts - and have been trying to read up on "combined series and parallel CD circuits".
But I just can't "connect the dots" between what I've seen, and the admittedly absurdly simple thing I want to do.

So, I bought some really tiny -- maybe 1mm? -- "smd" type LEDs from Amazon.  I tried to add a photo but was unsuccessful, so the description is that the "chip size" for all of them is given as "0805 (2012)"; I was thinking of simulating a flame by using "randomly"-fading of the following:

3 to maybe 5 Yellow___120-150mcd_____2V-2.2V_____20mA

1 or 2 Red______120-150mcd_____2V-2.2V_____20mA

and occasional flashes of

1 White____180-210mcd_____2V-3.2V_____20mA

I assume I'd have to do at least 3 strings of serial LEDs, with those strings connected in parallel.

I want to run them off of rechargable Lithium-Ion batteries; I do know that the TinyLily and the LilyPad use small "JS" connectors to run off of small-sized ones that I can also get on Amazon, which would be good because I can carve a small base to hold the electronics.

And that's as far as I can get.  I had hoped to use something like the "lily"-type boards to connect a USB port, a Battery connection, a battery *charger*, all as a single unit, but I can't get from "one LED plus a battery connection", to what I want to do.

Meanwhile, if I actually need to get a mini-"perf"-board and do some soldering, I can do that if I know what components I need and how to plan the circuit, but again, there are simple examples, and then nothing in between those and examples far more complex than anything I'd even try to do.

I could probably just buy a bunch of "flameless candles" and gut them to use the working part, but I dislike unnecessarily adding junk to the landfill.

If anyone can give a link to any diagrams or references or instructions or something like "How to do DC LED effects" or some other intermediate DC-circuits book, that would also be great, because I am at such a complete loss, that any info would be a Holiday Miracle for me, Heh! ;)

Thank you!

- Kris

Comment: There's a lot of information here that isn't particularly relevant and that makes it hard to understand what it is that you want. I'd suggest clarifying what the specific problem is and adding a couple of pictures of what you've got so far and what you would like to do.

Comment: Addressable LEDs are commonly used for projects like this since you can program whatever pattern/colors you want with less complex wiring

Comment: Yellow LEDs, which randomly blinks, exist. I got that from ali.

Comment: you could buy an LED tealight and use the parts ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=led+tealights&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Is this how I reply...?  Thank you for replying; I actually had thought of that, and I might in the end, but I would really like to learn how to do this, in part because it would be a stepping stone to other projects, especially when I start making my sculptures a bit larger ;) 



 I have seen circuits online that use various methods to fade or blink LEDs, and I've been trying to figure out how to combine that.

Comment: Hello ChrisD91 - I haven't yet figured out how to add images to posts here, sorry.  Diagrams are easier for me than descriptions.
Thank you, though, for reading and for considering my question; I'll work on clarifying my thoughts.

Comment: they now make fairy string lights that are ws2812 compat, making it easy to control dozens of RGB leds with only 3 connections. you would have to come up with a flame program, but there's a lot of neopixel libraries and animation routines in the wild you can "borrow" and customize.

Comment: @dandavis - I looked into those after reading your reply, and they're too large.  But it's an interesting suggestion and thank you for replying!

Comment: UPDATE:
Well, I found 3mm LEDs, with the "flicker" built right in - I actually had not realized they existed!!!  I bought some, and actually managed to get a working setup, although the first attempt got to be the *ugliest* circuit ever assembled, LOL!  But it was a step in the right direction.  It's just difficult when one's ideas are so far beyond the knowledge needed to implement them, so again, I appreciate all of your answers and advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only need to simulate color-changing and flickering of the light source, and not actual motion, you only need a single RGB LED.

The greater challenge will be mounting the LED in your "bubble bead" and running wires (at least 3 to provide power, ground, and signal) to that from your microcontroller board.

Instead, think about using a ready-made microcontroller board that *includes* an RGB LED on it, and use a "light pipe" to carry the light into the center of your sculpture. You can make that with fiber optics, or just a rod of transparent acrylic plastic.

There are libraries for driving RGB LEDs from various microcontroller boards. Start at the Adafruit website, which has tutorials.

Comment: Good ideas, Thank You!  I didn't even know that there are microcontrollers with integrated LEDs but now I know they exist, I can research that; it seems like it would simplify matters, which is good since this will be my first electronics project ever (I always tend to plunge into things with both feet...)  
The idea of motion is something I had not thought about at all; that could be fun on larger items!
Thank you for all of those good ideas :)